# FindFileFirst() Invalid handle value for every path

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to get FindFileFirst() windows API call to work and it's totally failing on every attempt. I've tried *.*, C:\*.*, *.txt, C:\*.txt and yet it doesn't even iterate down directory names. Not sure what to try anymore. I'm getting ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 2 (0x2) back when I call GetLastError(). Thanks for any help you can give.

```
HANDLE hFind;
LPWIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;

hFind = FindFirstFile("*.*", &FindFileData);

if(hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("\nFindFirstFile failed (%u)\n",GetLastError());
    return;
}

do
{
    if(FindFileData->dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
    {
        if(FindFileData->cFileName[0] != '.')
            continue;
        else
            searchDir(makePath(path, FindFileData->cFileName));
    }

    printf("Found %s %s\n",
        FindFileData->dwFileAttributes,FindFileData->cFileName);
    FindClose(hFind);
}
while(FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));

FindClose(hFind);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LPWIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;

You are using FindFileData pointer without allocating memory to it.

use this way.. ("remove LP")

WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData; // this will use stack memory

then refer to members like FindFileData.dwFileAttributes instead of  FindFileData->dwFileAttributes

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure to double slashes the path

i.e. "`c:\\*.*`"

it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

And now a surprise from [FindFirstFile Function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> As stated previously, you cannot use a
> trailing backslash () in the
> lpFileName input string for
> FindFirstFile, **therefore it may not be**
> **obvious how to search root**
> **directories**. If you want to see files
> or get the attributes of a root
> directory, the following options would
> apply:
>
> - To examine files in a root directory,    you can use "C:*" and
>   step through    the directory by using
>   FindNextFile.
> - To get the attributes of a root directory, use the GetFileAttributes
>   function.

For example you cannot use `"C:\\*.txt"` to search for the text files in the root directory
but in subdirectories it'll work.